# Get Mobile Number From Contacts and Block that number in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to get a number from user or select a number from contact list and block that number. I am able to get contacts from my contact list with check box, now i want when i click on number and press Block Number the number will be block. I have tried all these links

I am able to block a number define in the code. Now i want to select contact from my contact list and press block number the number will block

```
public class BlockCallReceiver <MyAdapter> extends  BroadcastReceiver{

    Context context;
    protected static final String TAG = null;
    public String[] Contacts = {};
    public int[] to = {};
    public ListView myListView;
    ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phno0 = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected String toNumbers;


    Cursor mCursor = getContacts();
    startManagingCursor(mCursor);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mCursor,
            Contacts = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
            to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    myListView = getListView();
    myListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);


     clear_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selection Cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ClearSelections();
        }
    });

    *//** When 'Done' Button Pushed: **//*

    done_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick (View v){

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("03234371984", null, "What's Up!!" , null, null);

            String name = null;
            String number = null;
            long [] ids = myListView.getCheckedItemIds();
            for(long id : ids) {
                Cursor contact = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id + "" }, null);
                while(contact.moveToNext()){
                    name = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    //name+=name;
                    number = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    //number+=number;
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " +name + "\n" + "Number: " + number , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}


private void ClearSelections() {
int count = this.myListView.getAdapter().getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    this.myListView.setItemChecked(i, false);
}
     }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private Cursor getContacts() {
// Run query
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '"
        + ("1") + "'";
String[] selectionArgs = null;
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
        sortOrder);

 }

 private Cursor managedQuery(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
 }


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
     if (myBundle != null)
      {
         System.out.println("--------Not null-----");
         try 
         {
          if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) 
          { 
              String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
              System.out.println("--------in state-----");
              if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
              { 
                  // Incoming call
                String incomingNumber    =intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                System.out.println("03335222339"+incomingNumber);
                System.out.println("03234371984"+incomingNumber);
                System.out.println("03244211843"+incomingNumber);
                System.out.println("03006041071"+incomingNumber);
                System.out.println("03056603902"+incomingNumber);
                System.out.println("03224444774"+incomingNumber);

                // this is main section of the code,. could also be use for particular number.
                // Get the boring old TelephonyManager.
                      TelephonyManager telephonyManager =(TelephonyManager)   context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                      // Get the getITelephony() method                          

                      Class<?> classTelephony = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());

                      Method methodGetITelephony = classTelephony.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

                      // Ignore that the method is supposed to be private                          
                      methodGetITelephony.setAccessible(true);

                      // Invoke getITelephony() to get the ITelephony interface
                      Object telephonyInterface = methodGetITelephony.invoke(telephonyManager);

                      // Get the endCall method from ITelephony
                      Class<?> telephonyInterfaceClass = Class.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass().getName());
                      Method methodEndCall = telephonyInterfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");

                      // Invoke endCall()
                      methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);

              }

            }
           }
          catch (Exception ex) 
          { // Many things can go wrong with reflection calls
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
         }
}
```

}

[Block Calls  programmatically](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html)

[Block Calls  programmatically](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/manipulating-incoming-ougoing-calls-tutorial-for-android/)

[image: When user select a number and press Block button the number will be block]

When user select a number and press Block Number button the number will be block